# Actionscript3: Help calculate where stage x=0 would be on a scrolling background

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

my platformer flash game has a scrolling background linked to a variable called scrollX. As the character moves to the right, the background's x value depreciates as it gets further off screen and away from 0 on the stage. What I want to do is to have a purple circle that is a child of the background that stays at where 0,0 on the stage is (top left corner of the screen). As it stands this code makes the purple circle travel along the top of the screen to the right as the player moves until it is off-screen (it doesn't sit static at the top left corner while the background scrolls).

Help in calculating this would be awesome. Thanks.

```
if (upPressed) {
    ySpeed -= speedConstant;
} else if (downPressed) {

    //ySpeed += speedConstant;
}

if (leftPressed) {
    xSpeed -= speedConstant;

} else if (rightPressed) {
    xSpeed += speedConstant;


}


if (downCollide) {
    if (ySpeed > 0) {
        ySpeed = 0;
    }
    if (upPressed) { //and if the up arrow is pressed
        ySpeed = jumpConstant; //set the y speed to the jump constant
    }
} else { //if player is not touching the footpath
    ySpeed += gravityConstant; //accelerate downwards
}

xSpeed *= friction;
ySpeed *= friction;
//if (enemySprite.x < -190) {
//enemySprite.x += 200

//}

scrollX -= xSpeed;
enemyScroll += xSpeed;
smallEnemy.x = enemyScroll;
scrollY -= ySpeed;
backG.x = scrollX;
backG.y = scrollY;
```

Comment: `smallEnemy` is the purple circle you are trying to move? Are you sure it's a child of `backG`?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a local `Point` (x,y relative to parent) to a global `Point` (x,y relative to stage) and back again using the `localToGlobal` and `globalToLocal` methods of the `DisplayObject` class.

For your case, you might have something like this:

```
bg.x = scrollX;
bg.y = scrollY;

var circleStagePt:Point = new Point(0, 0); // relative to stage
var circleLocalPt:Point = bg.globalToLocal(circleStagePt); // relative to bg

bg.purpleCircle.x = circleLocalPt.x;
bg.purpleCircle.y = circleLocalPt.y;
```

You'd need to readjust the circle's x and y every time you adjust the background position.

Seems like a much simpler and clearer solution would be to **not** make the circle a child of the background, though.